# Fat Free Framework routing not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fat-free-framework

I developed a website using Fat-Free Framework. Everything worked fine locally (on MaMP). I was able to acces the right routes ...

But now that I've moved it to a server, in a subfolder  (something like: **domaine/site**) the routing stopped working.

I've checked for mode_rewrite and it is enabled.

Here is my .htaccess file (the one in **domaine/site**):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

I've also tried this .htaccess but with not much success:
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* /site/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Should there be a .htaccess in **domaine/** ??

Any ideas ?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @AceMure1thi When I was accessing something like , /site/foo/bar it was looking at the actual path, so basically the RewriteRule was ignored...I managed to make it work , but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

So basically my problem was that the RewriteRule wasn't working when it should have. When I was accessing, let's say, **domaine/site/foo/bar**, instead of rewriting that to **domaine/site/** so that index.php would be called, the actual **foo/bar** folder was trying to be reached.

What I had forgotten to do was allowing overrides. So I just had to change the `AllowOverride` to `All` for my **VirtualHost** in the apache config file.

```
<Directory />
        ...
        AllowOverride All
        ...
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps.